# What single line query can be used in SQL to display usernames from transaction history?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables :Users and transactions

Table structure:

Users:
USERID
USERNAME
PASSWORD
EMAILID

Transactions:

```
    TRANSACTIONID
    AMOUNT
    EXPENSEID
    USERID_1 (refers to user who owes money)
    USERID_2 (refers to user who is owed money)
    STATUS
```

I want to display the usernames of userid_1 and userid_2 from the transaction table along with the amount and status where either userid_1 or userid_2 matches a particular user(say user 7)

Comment: Kindly post your tables as a text and not as an image.

Comment: @the_coding_cat Does this serve the purpose, I am new at asking questions

Comment: Here is the full guide on [Asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Simply join transaction table with users table twice to get names for the userid_1 and userid_2
2. Include a `WHERE` clause to match the user you want to look at (say user 7)

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e7ebeddf315fb237245b4ccc96391907)

```
SELECT u1.username AS userid_1_name, u2.username AS userid_2_name, t.amount, t.status
FROM transactions t 
JOIN users u1 ON u1.userid = t.userid_1
JOIN users u2 ON u2.userid = t.userid_2
WHERE t.userid_1 = 7 OR t.userid_2 = 7;
```